# change font-family of label

Tags: html, css

Please check this fiddle [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwudz9ph/) (the code here is just a raw code, my actual code has some bootstrap classes)

what I am trying to achieve here is that whenever user clicks on an input box, the font-family changes.

But unfortunately it works only if label is after input. 
I saw in many other answers in SO, it is mentioned that there is no css way to access a preceding element.
so, is there anyway to change the font-family of the label for the first two fields in the below

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    input:focus+label {
      font-family: 'Roboto Medium', sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #000;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div>
      <label for="name">username</label>
      <input type="text" name="name">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="email">email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email">
    </div>

    <br><br>
    <input type="text" name="color">
    <label for="color">your fav color</label>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would be to swap them in markup and then float the `label`'s left

This way the sibling selector `+` will work since the `input` is before the `label` in the markup

```css
.swap label {
  float: left;
}

input:focus+label {
  font-family: 'Roboto Medium', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="swap">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <label for="name">username</label>
  </div>
  <div class="swap">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <label for="email">email</label>
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="color">
  <label for="color">your fav color</label>
</form>
```

You can also use absolute position, a padding and then put `label` above..

```css
.swap {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.swap + .swap {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.swap label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

input:focus+label {
  font-family: 'Roboto Medium', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="swap">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <label for="name">username</label>
  </div>
  <div class="swap">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <label for="email">email</label>
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="color">
  <label for="color">your fav color</label>
</form>
```

..or left

```css
.swap {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 80px;
}
.swap + .swap {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.swap label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

input:focus+label {
  font-family: 'Roboto Medium', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="swap">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <label for="name">username</label>
  </div>
  <div class="swap">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <label for="email">email</label>
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="color">
  <label for="color">your fav color</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is unfortunately no predecessor selector in css.
This can be done if you target browsers that support flexbox - see this

**HTML**

```
 <form>
        <div class="some-container">
            <input type="text" name="name">
            <label for="name">username</label>
        </div>
        <div class="some-container">
            <input type="email" name="email">
            <label for="email">email</label>
        </div>

        <br><br>
            <input type="text" name="color">
            <label for="color">your fav color</label>
        </form>
```

**CSS**

```
.some-container {
            display: flex;
      align-items:center
        }
        .some-container label {
            order: 1;
      margin-right:10px;
        }
        .some-container input {
            order: 2;
      width:200px;
        }
        .some-container input:focus + label {
            font-family: 'Roboto Medium', sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
            color: #000;
            font-weight: 500;
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nithincharly/j96cnas2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is working fine for me, but I am afraid I don't totally understand that how adding display: flex and order helped. If it is not too much to ask, can you please point me to some link or elaborate on this

Answer (score 0):

you cannot focus a previous element in CSS..
can be handled with JavaScript.